# wxPython - Set dictionary as event object

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I would like to set a dictionary as an event object, but SetEventItem is expecting an object of type wxObject. What's the best way to go around this?

Basically, I have a settings dialog. If the "Apply All" button is pressed, an event is generated which will propagate up to some parent window, which can then set the settings to all the appropriate children. I have these settings stored in a dictionary. Is there a better way to do this? This seemed the simplest to me.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using `wx.lib.pubsub`

Comment: I was under the impression that Events and Binding has replaced pubsub

Comment: its different ... both exist ... and pubsub is pretty dang easy and does exactly what you are asking for ...

Comment: the EventObject is the originating GUI element ... it is not really used for data passing typically(although you can sort of pass data through it) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetEventObject` is used to set the originating GUI element not to pass data to the event listeners ...

you could certainly add a `GetValue` method to your GUI element that returned your dictionary... and then use `GetEventObject().GetValue()` to get your dictionary

alternatively the `wx.lib.pubsub` module is designed to pass data to event subscribers and I would recommend using this, for this particular use case ...